# How to include a nested component without its page selector

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a page with this html

```
<ion-content>
  <page-etapas-processo></page-etapas-processo>
  <page-retorno-financeiro></page-retorno-financeiro>
</ion-content>
```

Each component's declaration:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-retorno-financeiro',
  providers: [RetornoFinanceiroService],
  templateUrl: 'retorno-financeiro.html'
})
```

&

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-etapas-processo',
  providers: [AcompanhamentosService],
  templateUrl: 'etapas-processo.html',
})
```

When those pages are rendered they have an output like this

```
<page-retorno-financeiro>
...
</page-retorno-financeiro>

<page-etapas-processo>
...
</page-etapas-processo>
```

**I would like to render those pages without that selector tag surrounding them.
How to do that?**

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: You're always going to need a router or selector template to render a template. If you swap to a router vs. selected it will display the router DOM instead of selector DOM

Comment: @torazaburo I'm trying to solve a bigger problem with that, if there is no way to do what I want, I would have to try another thing. A margin-bottom calculated by ionic framework problem.

Comment: If you have some style problems with these, you can just set `display: block;` on these "unknown" HTML element or some other display value.

Comment: @EdmundoRodrigues yeah that's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just override the `margin-bottom`?

Comment: @torazaburo I can, but it's calculated by the framework, so I would have to preview all kind of devices to create a '@media' and override the right way